# A Linux server for audio processing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, server

I am working on a system that works as follows:

1. A user sends a 10-second frame of an audio signal (e.g., input.wav file) to the server over the internet.
2. The server processes the audio signals and outputs an audio file (e.g., output.wav)
3. The server sends output.wav to the user over the internet.

I was wondering what is the easiest way of implementing such a scenario. In other words, how we can build a Linux server on a personal computer that listens to the user's requests and send the output file to the user after processing.

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Arsalan

Comment: That's an awfully vague question. Have you done any research yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.
The specifics will require further detail however.

Based on the parameters you indicated, I would suggest you look at SoX (at least to get you started).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoX

If this is intended to attach to some sort of web interface, you will have to look at another product to handle that aspect of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete list of audio options (if SoX does not suit your purpose):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_audio_software